# What is the dipole moment of a typical transmon qubit?

Tags: experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing

What is the dipole moment of a typical transmon qubit?

I know this depends on the specific size, and that that varies from design to design. So let me provide an example situation:

[image: from: https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.4848]

So given this size and shape (~100 $\mu$m x 100 $\mu$m)  and material (aluminum), how does one go on to calculate the dipole moment?